# Display a list of single values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say

```
SELECT 'Max' AS Foo
```

results into a result with one field. But there are also ways to give multiple values into your SQL application like

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Name IN ('Max','Tim')
```

question:

Is there also a way to display multiple rows like

```
SELECT ('Max','Tim') AS Foo
```

Comment: Could you not use concat?

Comment: The answer to this question totally depends on the version of SQL you are using.  "SQL" is just a language, not an actual product.  Which version of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) ?

Comment: I believe STUFF() function should work for you.

Comment: SQL Server has no notion of tuples, arrays or nested tables -- you can't have one column take on multiple values. The only natural representation of multi-values in SQL Server is as rows of a table. Alternate representations include concatenated strings, XML and JSON, but those are not as efficient as rowsets and require "unpacking" on the client end, so the right solution depends on what you're doing. If you actually want multiple rows from constants, use `UNION ALL` or [`VALUES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like below

```
 SELECT  Stuff(
  (SELECT N', ' + Name FROM table_name  where  Name IN ('Max','Tim')
   FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
  .value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,N'') as name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use union statement

```
select 'max' as foo
union 
select 'tim' as foo
```